# Change dimensions of controls frame around clipped object

Tags: fabricjs

is it possible to change the dimensions of the controls frame around a clipped object?
I use "clipTo" to apply a SVG mask to an image. The problem is that the clipped image still has the dimensions and the centerpoint of the original image. I need a solution to get a clipped image that has the dimensions an the centerpoint af the SVG masked I used for clipping.

Cheers,
Robster

Comment: Ok, got this one working. Don't know if that's the right way, but I used toDataURL to get the pixel data of the masked object. Then I created a new object from that pixel data using fabric.Image.fromURL and the dataURL as source. Works like a charm for me :-)

Comment: Nice, I think gonna use this too, but I will need to specify toDataURL's top, left, width and height to fit clipped area.