# fabricjs: how to size bounding box after clip image

Tags: fabricjs

I have a canvas where I load an image and then draw a rectangle to select part of the image and then clip to that area. That all works fine.

However the bounding rectangle for the remaining image is still the same size as the original image.  How do I get the bounding box to size to the clipped image?

I have tried img.setCoord() and that has no effect.

Rick

Comment: Another potentially anwered similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622618/change-dimensions-of-controls-frame-around-clipped-object)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the properties of the bounding rectangle:

```
var bound = event.target.getBoundingRect();
```

And change the properties of the bound object, in your case will be the size of the cropped image:

```
bound.width = 25;
bound.left = 32;
bound.top = 63;
bound.height = 3;
```

Comment: changing the ```bound``` values would NOT mutate ```target.getBoundingRect```